# xsd:complexType with children, attributes, and restrictions

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm working on creating a schema, but am getting stuck near my root element with defining it as a complexType that has children, attributes, *and* restrictions on those attributes

This is what I have tried so far.... (venetian blind format)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsd:element name="foos">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="foo" type="FooType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>         
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="FooType">
    <xsd:attribute name="exchangeType" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="S" />
                <xsd:enumeration value="T" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="thing1" type="Thing1Type" />
        <xsd:element name="thing2" type="Thing2Type" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I've been having trouble finding a way to incorporate this attribute and its restrictions

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two main corrections:**

1. An `xsd:attribute` declaration cannot have both a local
   `xsd:simpleType` and a `@type` attribute; deleted the `@type`
   attribute.
2. An `xsd:attribute` declaration cannot appear before `xsd:sequence`;
   move it after.

**XSD with corrections applied:**

This XSD has the above corrections and a few other minor fixes applied and is now valid:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsd:element name="foos">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="foo" type="FooType" 
                     minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>         
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="FooType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="thing1" type="Thing1Type" />
      <xsd:element name="thing2" type="Thing2Type" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="exchangeType" use="required">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="S" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="T" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="Thing1Type"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="Thing2Type"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, @kjhughes, this makes a lot more sense and is the clarity I needed on how to approach this